# Overflow hidden/visible messing up my view

Tags: html, css

I'm confused about why my paragraph doesn't begin in a new line based on the overflow property of the previous element.

Check out my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/11GfJmJWvBLNKqyAck8E?p=preview), change the overflow property in `line 11` to `hidden` and it will work fine. On `visibile`, it screws up the view.

I know doing a clearfix can fix this issue, but what I'm interested in is why overflow is doing this to my view;

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible; /* Change this to visible/hidden*/
}
```

Comment: Please include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself for those who cant access plunker :(

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear you something overflow:hidden make the UL clear because it is shorter form of `:after{clear:both;content:"";display:block;}` 
but in `overflow:hidden` it clears it self and take it's height but nothing will be shown outside of this.

In this example you have floating elements and the parents UL is not taking its width and height that is why paragraph goes beside to it. when you add `overflow:hidden` then UL takes its height and width  because it is shorter form of has layout property `:after{clear:both;content:"";display:block;}`

Hope so you will be cleared by this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that because your ul has `float: left;` the text element goes by default on its right. So when you add the `overflow: hidden;` property it clears the area around the list.

There is also a [great read](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) for floating elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the property of **float left in anchor**. **Remove** overflow property from **ul**, it will work excellent.

Add the following properties in css to:

```
ul{ font-size:0px;}
ul li{ vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;}
ul li a{ font-size:16px; float:none;}
```